# How to get object dictionary representation in Python

Tags: python-3.x, class, object

I have objects **message** of type *azure.servicebus.common.message.Message*. I can print it and get representation that looks like dictinorary.

```
print(message)
{b'Type': b'TEST', b'Subtype': b'subtype'}
print(type(message))
<class 'azure.servicebus.common.message.Message'>
print(dict(message))
TypeError: 'Message' object is not iterable
```

I would like to add dictionary representation of this object to the list, not the object like below

```
batch.append(message)
```

How to convert representation of the object to dictionary ?

Comment: Doesn't `dict(message)` (or `str(message)`) work? It is unclear to me what do you mean by *"dictionary representation"*.

Comment: @DeepSpace what you are looking at is not a dict, but rather as the OP says a "representation that looks like dictionary". @irom I agree it seems that a dictionary (or something like one) is being used internally, perhaps you can check how `Message.__str__` is implemented to find out where it comes from?